# Having issue with deleting row (using button in column) in dojogrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo, delete-row

I am using dojo EnhancedGrid to display some data and handling "onRowClick" event to allow the user to click on a row in the grid to view more details about this row like below.

dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", grid, dojo.partial(displayDetailsForSelectedElement, type) );

Now, I want to allow the user to delete an item from the grid by providing a delete button in separate column for each of the row in the grid. The code for the button is provided below.

```
 function buttonFormatterRemove(col, rowIndex){
    var w = new dijit.form.Button({
        label: "Delete",    //label: '<img src="images/del.png" />',
        iconClass: "dijitIconDelete", //"dijitEditorIcon  dijitIconCut",
        showLabel: false,
        onClick: function() {
                console.log(this);
                //if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the assertion?")){
                    alert("Do I come here for delete...");

                    //var item = grid.selection.getSelected();
                    //var work_id = grid.store.getValue(item[0], "work_id");
                    var item = this.grid.getItem(rowIndex);
                    var id = item['id'];
                    alert("delete row with id = " + id);

                    //Send POST request to delete
                    require(["dojo/request"], function(request){
                        request.del(contextPath + "/rest/items/" + id)
                            .then(function(text){
                                    console.log("The server returned: ", text);
                                });
                    });      
                //}          
        }//function
    });
    w._destroyOnRemove=true;
    return w;
}
```

The issue I am having is that when I click on the delete button for a row, though it does come inside onClick(), the code after alert("Do I come here for delete..."); doesn't get invoked. After, it executed first alert(), it calls displayDetailsForSelectedElement() to handle 'onRowClick'.

I am not sure if this issue is due to the fact that 2 events are fired when I click on delete button and if there is a solution to fix this? Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may call `dojo.stopEvent(e)` firstly to stop the event propagation in your delete method.